# Need help to find a bug in simple Objective-C code for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Obj-C programming and I cannot figure out an issue in my code.
Below I pasted pieced of code from different classes...
When I run my application I am getting zero value for _pirate.health, zero value for _pirate.weapon.damage and (null) for _pirate.weapon.name

I have no idea why it does not work. I am so desperate right now :(
I will appreciate your help!

***ViewController.h***

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NCharacter *pirate;
```

***ViewContoller.m***

```
_pirate.health = 100;
_pirate.weapon.damage = 10;
_pirate.weapon.name = @"Fist";
```

***Character.h***

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NWeapon *weapon;
@property (nonatomic) int health;
```

***Character.m***

```
@implementation NCharacter

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _weapon = [[NWeapon alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

***NWeapon.h***

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int damage;
```

***NWeapon.m***

```
@implementation NWeapon
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name= [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you ever alloc initing the character? Or is _pirate.health the first call?

Comment: In your Controller you should first call (you'd do it in `viewDidLoad` method) something like `self.pirate = [[NCharacter alloc] init];`

Comment: @WilliamGeorge erm... I create *pirate object in ViewController.h and as I understand it goes to the class Character and makes initialization which is in Character.m...
Probably I am wrong, but as I understand it is how it works... no?

Comment: @Cojoj isn't it enough that I allocate memory for Character object in Character.m?

Comment: @PutinHuylo No, as @Cojoj says, in `ViewController.h` you will need to `_pirate = [[NCharacter alloc] init];` before the call to `.health`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you never alloc the property `self.pirate` - Assigning the property in the header file doesn't automatically create the object for you. Therefore before any calls to your `NCharacter` methods you will need to `alloc] init];`

Try this:

```
_pirate = [[NCharacter alloc] init];
_pirate.health = 100;
_pirate.weapon.damage = 10;
_pirate.weapon.name = @"Fist";
```

In some scenarios it can be useful to lazy load properties. Todo so in your `ViewController.m` create the following:

```
-(NCharacter *)pirate
{
    if(!_pirate){
        _pirate = [[NCharacter alloc] init];
    }

    return _pirate;
}
```

Therefore you will be able to use something similar to what you had before

```
self.pirate.health = 100;
self.pirate.weapon.damage = 10;
self.pirate.weapon.name = @"Fist";
```

The call to `self.pirate` will instantiate the object for you.

Comment: One question.. do I need then the following code in Character.m:
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _weapon = [[NWeapon alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

Because I feel like I allocate space two times... no?